# HTML Javascript about array.

Tags: javascript, html

I am still new to JavaScript. I need to create a button in html and allow the user to click the button to change the specify body background color.

```
var colors = ["purple", "yellow", "black"];
```

Above is the given array in the JavaScript. If the user click more than 3 times (after blue color), the green color will be selected again.

```
<form>
<p><input type="button" value="Change Color" name="B1" onclick="changeColor()"></p>
</form>
```

I roughly write the function for the button, but i did not know how i can assign the color from the array to the background color

```
function changeColor()
{   
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="colors[i]";
    i++
    if(i >=2)
    {
     i = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can correct my code.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a `var i = 0;` somewhere outside `changeColor`. Next just use `document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to define global i variable, that will keep your current index. Than check if it's value extends array length, if so, than you should reset it, to the array start.

```
var colors = ["purple", "yellow", "black"];
var i = 0; // define global i variable
function changeColor()
{   
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i++];
    if(i >= colors.length)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest implementation:

```
var colors = ["purple", "yellow", "black"];
var i = 0;
function changeColor()
{   
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    ++i;
    if(i >= colors.length)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Little bit mistake in your logic,

Here is what you want.

```js
var colors = ["purple", "yellow", "black"];
var i = 0;

function changeColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  if (i >= 2) {
    i = 0;
    return;//Return without incresing it when it becomes 0 again.
  }
  i++;//Move increment to bottom of page.
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Change Color" name="B1" onclick="changeColor()">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Replace if (i >= 2)  with array.length, hardcoding max iterator value is dangerous:)

Comment: @Beri ,You are right, Answer is just related to questions logic for better understanding to Firion Redfield.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the 'best' way to do it, although the code is more difficult to understand than the other answers:

```
var changeColor = (function(){
    var colors = ["purple", "yellow", "black"], i=0;    
    return function(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i++ % colors.length];
    };
}());
```

By declaring the `i` and `colors` variables inside an anonymous function you avoid creating global variables, and prevent any other code from accessing these values.

By using the `%` remainder operator with `colors.length` you can add/remove colors from the array without changing any other part of your code.

Comment: I understand that :), never thought to use modulo for the array size.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the array reference in quotes. Variables are not expanded inside quotes. So just assign the array reference to the style:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
```

Comment: Thx :) it helpful for me